# How can I name the output array in jq?

Tags: jq

Here's my JSON input

```json
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "age": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "age": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "age": 3
  }
]
```

I want filer out only the `name` fields and create an array named `names`

```json
{
  "names": [
    {
      "name": "A"
    },
    {
      "name": "B"
    },
    {
      "name": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```bash
jq '{names: [.[] | {name: .name}]}'
```

Alternatively, we use a few shortcuts produces the shorten the above.

```bash
jq '{names: map({name})}'
```

Comment: It could be even shorter - `{names : map({name})}`